Flash action when changed tab in React native Android app
I'm using expo with several tabs like
this appear
How can i change or disable that action flashing.
This is my tab option props
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme ?? 'light'].tint,
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarBackground: TabBarBackground,
        tabBarStyle: Platform.select({
          ios: {
            // Use a transparent background on iOS to show the blur effect
            position: 'absolute',
          },
          default: {},
        }),
      }}>```

